# minimum comparison model

Tags: algorithms

Given n real numbers, we want to determine their min in the comparison model. (Comparisons cost one unit each, bookkeeping is free.)
Prove: n − 2 comparisons do not suffice.

I proved n-1 comparisons suffice by a simple linear scan algorithm and i've tried to approach this with a proof by contradiction but it doesn't seem rigorous enough. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hint:  well, it doesn't work if $n=2$, so let $n$ be the least $n$ for which $n-2$ comparisons does work.  Now argue that you can handle $n-1$ numbers in $n-3$ comparisons.